# Record video with overlay image in android

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-view, video-recording

Is it possible to record video with overlay view? While recording the video I have displayed one small image on the overlay view. What I want to do is I want those overlay image along with the video recorded. So when I will open that recorded video, I will be able to see that overlapped image that recorded with video also.

Friends, I need this solution ASAP. Please suggest proper solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way in the current Android API to get between the camera input and the encoder.  Any solution would either involve capturing frames from the video source, overlaying the additional image, and then including an encoder for the captured frames.  Even in native code with NEON optimizations on a fast system, this is going to be a slow process.  Alternatively, the whole stream could be post-processed in a similar fashion, but this would also require a decoder.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: This is possible using the [CameraView](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) library, at least in "snapshot video" mode.